# How can delay loading from StreamingAssets in Unity WebGL?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have few Unity WebGL projects which load very slowly. (stored on Amazon S3 cloud)
testing revealed that all the project including the entire content of StreamingAssets is loaded on start before the game begins.

How can I make the game NOT to load from streamingAssets unless the asset is called to play or a coded command is given?